# Some doubts about Levy's Continuity Theorem proof - Convergence results

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

> **THEOREM (Levy's Continuity Theorem)**
>   Let $(\mu_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $(\hat{\mu}_n)_{n\geq1}$ denote their characteristic functions (or Fourier transforms).
>   If $\hat{\mu}_n(u)$ converges to a function $f(u)$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and if in addition $f$ is continuous at $0$, then there exists a probability $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $f(u)=\hat{\mu}(u)$, and $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$.
>
> **A PART OF THE PROOF FOR $d=1$ (FIRST PART)**
>   $(\ldots)$ let $\beta=\dfrac{2}{\alpha}$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ constants) and we have the useful estimate
>   $$\mu_n\left(\left[-\beta,\beta\right]^c\right)\le\dfrac{\beta}{2}{\displaystyle \int_{-\frac{2}{\beta}}^{\frac{2}{\beta}}\left(1-\hat{\mu}_n(u)\right)du}\tag{1}$$
>   Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since by hypothesis $f$ is continous at $0$, there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $\left\vert1-f(u)\right\vert\le\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4}$ if $\left\vert u\right\vert\le\dfrac{2}{\alpha}$ (This is because $\hat{\mu}_n(0)=1$ for all $n$, whence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\hat{\mu}_n(0)=f(0)=1$ as well.) Therefore
>   $$\left\vert\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\displaystyle{\int_{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1-f(u)\right)du}\right\vert\le\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\displaystyle{\int_{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4}du}=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\tag{2}$$
>   $(\ldots)$ there exists an $N$ ($\in\mathbb{N}$) such that $n\geq\mathbb{N}$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) implies
>   $$\left\vert\displaystyle{\int_{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1-\hat{\mu}_n(u)\right)du} - {\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1-f(u)\right)du}\right\vert\le\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}\tag{3}$$
>   whence, by $(2)$, $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}{\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1-\hat{\mu}_n(u)\right)du}\le\varepsilon$. Next apply $(1)$ to conclude $\mu_n\left(\left[-\alpha, \alpha\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$, for all $n\ge N$.

*So far so good to me. The following* **SECOND PART** *is not that clear instead.*

> **A PART OF THE PROOF FOR $d=1$ (SECOND PART)**
>   There are only a finite number of $n$ before $N$, and for each $n<N$ there exists an $\alpha_n$ such that $\mu_n\left(\left[-\alpha_n, \alpha_n\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$. 
> Let $a=\max(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n;\alpha)$. Then 
>   $$\mu_n\left(\left[-a, a\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon,\hspace{0.3cm}\text{for all }n\tag{4}$$
>   The inequality $(4)$ means that for the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-a,a\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$. Therefore, we have shown
>   $$\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=0\tag{5}$$
>   for any fixed $m\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Given the first part, my doubts about* **SECOND PART** *of the proof are:*
1. Why can I be sure that "for each $n<N$ there exists an $\alpha_n$ such that $\mu_n\left(\left[-\alpha_n, \alpha_n\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$"?;
2. Why can I state that "the inequality $(4)$ means that for the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-a,a\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$"? More precisely, why can I draw a conclusion specifically on the $\sup\limits_n$ of the set $\mu_n\left(\left[-a,a\right]^c\right)$?;
3. Could I also state that the conclusion of all the reasoning is that $\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=\liminf\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=0$ (for any fixed $m\in\mathbb{R}$) and not just that $\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=0$ (for any fixed $m\in\mathbb{R}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Note that $\lim_{K \to \infty} \mu_n([-K,K]^c) = 0$. Thus choosing $K$ sufficiently large ensures that $\mu_n([-K,K]^c) \leq \epsilon$.

(2) If you have $\mu_n([-a,a] ^c) \leq \epsilon$ for all $n$, then this means that $\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $\{\mu_n([-a,a]^c): n \geq 1\}$. By definition of sup as the LEAST upper bound, we get
$$\sup \{\mu_n([-a,a]^c): n \geq 1\} \leq \epsilon$$

(3) Yes, you can do that. Recall that $\liminf_n a _n \le \limsup_n a_n$.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! First two points are perfectly clear to me now. As to the third one, just to be sure that the way in which I get to the conclusion is correct...I have that "the inequality $(4)$ means that for the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-a,a\right]^c\right)\le\varepsilon$" **[CONTINUE]** @ε-δ

Comment: **[CONTINUE]** From this, I deduce that, by definition of limits, *there exists a limit* for $\{\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-a,a\right]^c\right): n\ge1\}$, i.e. $\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=\liminf\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n}\mu_n\left(\left[-m,m\right]^c\right)=0$ @ε-δ

Comment: Yes, (4) just says that  $\lim_m \sup_n \mu_n([-m,m]^c) = 0$.

Comment: Which corresponds to $\lim_m \inf_n \mu_n([-m,m]^c)$, right? Since the part I quoted in the previous comments makes me think that that means that *there exists* a limit for the sequence, that is, by def., that $\liminf=\limsup=\lim$ @ε-δ

Comment: $\lim_n a_n = a \iff \limsup_n a_n = \liminf_n a_n = a$. Here, we have $0 \leq \liminf_n a_n \leq \limsup_n a_n = 0$ so $\liminf_n a_n = \limsup_n a_n = 0$ and we conclude $\lim_n a_n = 0.$

Comment: Thank you again for your patience, time and very exhaustive answer. Got it now :) @ε-δ

Comment: Glad to help! Have a nice day/night!

Comment: Thanks! You too :)